# Bootstrap grid text writing

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with bootstrap. I have created one grid. A circle is there inside that grid at left side. Now, I want to write some texts besides of that circle. But, whenever I am writing something, it's overlapping with circle. Text should not overlap with circle and vice versa. Specially, It should be responsive. That text part should have a proper margin. In mobile device, suppose content is large, then text should not go to the back of circle. It should increase the height of grid vertically to fill all the contents in it.

This is the problem which is happening, http://s24.postimg.org/8fp4y8c8l/Screen_Shot_2015_08_24_at_7_28_35_am.png

I am expecting something like this one,http://s3.postimg.org/951vbnupf/Screen_Shot_2015_08_24_at_7_31_00_am.png

This is my code :-

```css
.demo-content{
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 18px;
        min-height: 140px;
        background: #abb1b8;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        


padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
border-radius:5px;

}

#circle {
    background: #FFC40C; 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position:absolute;
    left:5%;
    top:13%;
    }
    .circle-posiiton {
        position:relative;
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div main="rowmain">
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12 circle-position">
         <div class="demo-content"><h1>Hi, Stack overflow. It is good.</h1>
        <div id="circle"></div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job that the CSS3 calc function could solve. Calculating a padding on content div from the position and width of the circle puts the text in the write place. Here's the CSS I added to your `.demo-content` class:

```
padding-left: -webkit-calc(5% + 105px);
padding-left: -moz-calc(5% + 105px);
padding-left: calc(5% + 105px);
```

I used vendor-prefixed versions too for maximum compatibility. And I used 5% for the position of the circle and 105px for the width of the circle with a 5px margin.

```css
.demo-content{
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 18px;
        min-height: 140px;
        background: #abb1b8;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding-left: -webkit-calc(5% + 105px);
        padding-left: -moz-calc(5% + 105px);
        padding-left: calc(5% + 105px);


padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
border-radius:5px;

}

#circle {
    background: #FFC40C; 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position:absolute;
    left:5%;
    top:13%;
    }
    .circle-posiiton {
        position:relative;
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div main="rowmain">
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12 circle-position">
         <div class="demo-content"><h1>Hi, Stack overflow. It is good.</h1>
        <div id="circle"></div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `.demo-content h1 { margin-left: 10%; }` in your [css](/questions/tagged/css) should help.